# Pyspark - how to parse a PowerShell string command into flag and arg dummy vectors

Tags: python, parsing, pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to detect anomalies in `PowerShell.exe` events, my dataset has powershell execution commands as free text, i.e., `powershell.exe -NoLogo -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\scripts\s.pa1`

Some `powershell.exe` flags (flags start with `-`) have optional arguments, in the example above, flag `-ExecutionPolicy` has an argument `Bypass`.

1. pyspark version: 2.3.0
2. python version: 3.7

One of the preprcess phases is to create a one hot representation to the flags and arguments, which I need to extract and generate from the free text. This process is extremely slow and memory consuming, especially when running on large datasets (in my case, ~60M rows), I need suggestions of how to accelerate the process (currently using a naive solution).

### What I want to do:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

powershell_df = spark.table('powershell_events')
powershell_df.show(10)

+------------------------------------+
|                          powershell|
+------------------------------------+
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -ep Bypass...|
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -ep Bypass...|
|powershell.exe -ep bypass -file c...|
|powershell.exe -ep Allsign -file ...|
|powershell.exe -File c:\usr\s.ps1...|
|powershell.exe -File c:\usr\f.ps1...|
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -ep Bypass...|
|powershell.exe -NoProf -ep Allsig...|
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -File c:\ ...|
|powershell.exe -NoProf -File c:\ ...|
+------------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

powershell_flag = [... all possible powershell arguments and arguments flags ...]

for flag in powershell_flags:
    powershell_df = powershell_df.withColumn(flag, F.when(F.col('powershell').contains(flag), 1).otherwise(0))

powershell_df.show(10)

+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---+-----+---+----------+-------------+---+
|                          powershell|-NoProfile|-NoLogo|-ep|-File|...|-ep_Bypass|-ep_Allsigned|...|
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---+-----+---+----------+-------------+---+
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -ep Bypass...|         0|      1|  1|    0|...|         1|            0|...|
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -ep Bypass...|         0|      1|  1|    0|...|         1|            0|...|
|powershell.exe -ep bypass -file c...|         0|      0|  1|    1|...|         1|            0|...|
|powershell.exe -ep Allsign -file ...|         0|      0|  1|    1|...|         0|            1|...|
|powershell.exe -File c:\usr\s.ps1...|         0|      0|  0|    1|...|         0|            0|...|
|powershell.exe -File c:\usr\f.ps1...|         0|      0|  0|    1|...|         0|            1|...|
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -ep Bypass...|         0|      1|  1|    0|...|         1|            0|...|
|powershell.exe -NoProf -ep Allsig...|         1|      0|  1|    0|...|         0|            1|...|
|powershell.exe -NoLogo -File c:\ ...|         0|      1|  0|    1|...|         0|            0|...|
|powershell.exe -NoProf -File c:\ ...|         1|      0|  0|    1|...|         0|            0|...|
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---+-----+---+----------+-------------+---+
only showing top 10 rows
```

As for right now, I have implemented a very naive code to extract such representation, but, it is extremely slow, in addition, the `powershell_flags` is a long list of every possible flags and arguments `powershell.exe` can get and it is not trivial to map an argument to a flag.

### What i tried so far:

tokenizing:

```
powershell_df = powershell_df.withColumn('tokens', F.split(F.col('powershell_df'), ' '))
```

To map flag arguments to flags I had to generate a dictionary where they key is a flag and the value is a list of possible arguments, for example:

```
data = {
        'ExecutionPolicy': ['Bypass', 'AllSigned', 'RemoteSigned', 'None' ...],
        'InputFormat': ['None', 'XML', ...], 
        ...
        }
```

and then I used `F.create_map` for each value, which takes forever to run and mostly raise a memory error.

Is there a more efficient way to generate such dummy columns?